# Why isnt the event listener going off more than once?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
const target = document.getElementById("button");

function when( event) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    target.addEventListener(event, resolve);
  });
}

when( "click").then(() => {
  alert("button clicked");
});
```

I dont understand why this event listener function wouldnt go off when you click more than once. Despite being in a promise, the event listener is "registered" to the button. So I feel like it should always go off when clicked.

Comment: A promise can only resolve once. The event listener is running every time you click, but calling `resolve()` doesn't do anything after the first time.

Comment: The event listener goes off multiple times. It just doesn't do anything with the promise that is already resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The function `when` returns a promise. This promise will resolve(and cause the alert) when event listener calls. Because **a promise can only resolve once**, the alert only triggers at the first time. After that, you can see `console.log('event listener calls')` when you click button but the alert would not trigger again.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("button");

function when( event) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    target.addEventListener(event, function() {
      console.log('event listener calls');
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

when( "click").then(() => {
  alert("button clicked");
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```